# How to optimize in an assignment problem when the objective function is a quotient?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming

I know that if I had an assignment problem with an objective function that looked like this

$${\max} \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\cdot x_{ij},$$

I could use linear programming to solve it. But this time I have to optimize this function

$${\max} \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n h_{ij}\cdot x_{ij}}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}\cdot x_{ij}}$$

and I don't think this can be done with linear programming. I'm not sure though. So if this is possible, how? And if it's not, are there other methods so solve those problems?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming

Comment: It's not linear and doesn't need to have a max. Consider $\frac{5x+3y}{6x+4y}$ this function approaches $\pm \infty$ (depending on your approach) as we get close to $6x+4y=0$.

Comment: linear fractional programming is exactly the thing I was looking for, thanks! Also thanks for the hint that those functions might not have a maximum. In my case though I know that both sides of the fraction are > 0, so it should have a maximum.